# Best way to calculate traffic usage

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, centos

I need to write an application to track traffic and disk usage. disk usage is easy but what's the best way to track traffic of the web site? Most of web hosting control panels offers such this feature but how do they do it? I'm using CentOS and Apache.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *best* way is to [combine instrumentation, telemetry and analytics](http://www.joyent.com/software/smartdatacenter/cloud-analytics/) to present a powerful yet easy-to-use suite of tools for capacity planning and performance analysis.

The easy way is to slurp your log files into a database and write a web application to display graphs and log entries that are interesting to you.

Comment: I'm not looking for any ready to use tool.

Comment: I was being facetious because you haven't given nearly enough information to say what "best" means to you. If you want to do it the absolute best way, copy Joyent. :)

Answer (score 0):

We use cacti:

http://www.cacti.net/

Cacti is a general purpose RRDtool front end that supports multiple types of hosts and graphs.  You can also construct a 95% graph useful if your bandwidth is charged on that basis.

Comment: I'm not looking for general traffic tracking tools.

Comment: Your question is then too vague.